# Replication Error: 'Binary log is not open'

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

Heyho,
I'm trying to set up a basic database replication from a MariaDB 5.5 master to a MariaDB 10 slave. Versions are non-negotiable, since I need the older version on the master and a multi-replication slave later on. I followed the instructions (several times over by now) and am always ending up with the following in the end:

`SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
[..]
Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open'
[..]`

Special circumstances outside the versioning are:

From the master, I have copied the database I want to replicate (via mysqldump and with --master-data) and a second one with a bunch of views in it (also with mysqldump, but not --master-data).
Master is opensuse, slave is centos.

I have found no related questions that have answers, so here I am...

Comment: I just noticed that there is no entry for Binlog_Do_DB and Binlog_Ignore_DB when looking at the master status on the master... Are those important?

Comment: Alright. One more update: I tried to set up a similar system and got it to work. Differences are: There may be a network issue on the original system. The original system is using a slave with MariaDB ver. 10.4.7, while the working system is a 10.2.25

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs, when the slave can connect to a database but does not find a binary log file. (Or can't open it for any reason.)
In this particular case, I had multiple master databases set up for a multi-master replication, but only one of them had the logging enabled. I mixed up the IP-adresses and connected to a machine that had a database, but no binary log.
Therefore, the error.